# Is palmistry haram in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, ilm-al-ghaib

I have heard some people saying that getting to know about your fate is strictly prohibited as Allah is the only one who knows everything. If palmistry is not allowed then what is the purpose of the lines in our hands?

Comment: You have such lines at every major articulation (elbow, wrist, knee), the lines in your hand only being the most complicated ones. There may not be any purpose, only skin being naturally folded into lines.

Comment: "what is the purpose of the lines in our hands?" Probably a better fit for [biology.se].

Answer (score 1):

Any knowledge which induces one to be curious to know which is unknowable and is part of God's knowledge is impermissible. The rationale behind that is that people tend to believe such practitioners as if they know the unseen and start resorting to them for the solutions of their unresolved problems; which denotes the lack of faith and trust in Allah, therefore in Islamic sharia'a all such profession are impermissible which my lead believers astray.